# Config setting for disabling page cache

Tags: config, cache

Is there a config setting for disabling page cache in EE? I've found a setting for disabling tag caching `$config['disable_tag_caching']` but not one for pages. I'm using the [Focus Lab master config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) setup and would like to easily turn off page caching in development. I usually use [CE Cache](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-cache) and are missing this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this on an EE1 site by setting the cache directory of the dev site to have read-only permissions and it works fine. However, I've not tried this on an EE2 site yet...

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I was thinking of doing that but was hoping for something more automated. I guess I can just use CE Cache when that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it. Seems someone else already asked the same thing over on the EL forums. The request makes perfect sense though. http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/198408/#932976